# Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, induction, catalan-numbers

I need to use the explicit formula for the Catalan numbers to show that $C_{n+1} \ge 2C_n$ I started with induction but am not sure how to use induction with a $\ge$ involved. Any method of proof is accepted

Comment: Maybe put in the explicit formula for the Catalan numbers into your question 
\begin{eqnarray*}
C_{n}=\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute this into the inequality & substitute factorials for the binomial coefficients ... cancel some of the factorials ... should be a doddle from there ?

Comment: Please state what explicit formula ou are supposed to use, and what you have tried already.

Comment: If it matters, the inequality, specifically $\geq$ in your case, does not effect how an induction proof would work or is styled.

Comment: There is no need for induction here. Use the explicit formula for $C_n$ to cancel common factors and simplify $C_{n+1}/C_n$ as much as possible. This should leave you with a very simple fraction that you should have no problem proving to be $\ge 2$.